# defining a vector of templated container class in a templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector

So I have two templated container classes (`Stationary` and `Case`), it makes sense to me to set the vector type in `Case` with `Stationary` type as the following example.

```
template <typename T>
class Stationary // T can be : Pencil, Pen...
{
    std::vector<T>items; 
};


template <typename T>
class Case // if T is Pencil, it is Pencil case
{
    std::vector<Stationary>case; 
};
```

What I found is

> 'Stationary' is not defined.

the solution that is provided in the comment section works in my sample code, 
but not in my project code, does custom constructor matter in this case?

Comment: Maybe `std::vector<Stationary<T>> codewords;`?

Comment: @Glenio Alsin Tan Stationary is a template name. You have to specify its arguments.

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan - Sorry but, given the errors you're reporting, your real code is more complex that the code in your example. You should show us a minimal but complete example code to reproduce the error.

Comment: @max66 don't say sorry man, I tried it with the sample code and it's give me the same error

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan The solution of _**max66**_ [solves the problem you have provided](https://godbolt.org/z/9oLKhz). If you have another error, please provide a minimal and reproducible example.

Comment: @max66 does custom constructor matter in this case?

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan what does your constructor look like?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot just simple constructors with one int parameter for both Stationary and Case, there are two constructors for each class probably like `Stationary(int)`   `Stationary(int, int)` same for the other two in the Case class

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan do you resize the vector somewhere?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot probably, because i create new stationary and add them to the case. My problem is the constructors in the Case class are not overloading

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan I mean, do you call `vector.resize(x)`, without the second parameter?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot no i dont

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan Then I think the new problem you have is unrelated to the question, you better ask another one with a minimal code that reproduce your compile time error. If on the other hand it's truely related to a missing template parameter, then edit the question to add the code that reproduce the error.

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan - "does custom constructor matter in this case? " - Well... I don't know. I we don't see all constructor it's difficult to say. Anyway, if gives problems, it's another type of problem. Unrelated with the absence of `<T>` inside `Case`